# Wonky dating in Java

Tags: java, date-parsing

The following Java code just parses a date (with time portion) `2009-01-28-09:11:12` using `SimpleDateFormat`. Let's have look at it.

```
final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {            
        try
        {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            Date d = df.parse("2009-01-28-09:11:12");
            System.out.println(d);
        }
        catch (ParseException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The date (with time) displayed (after parsing) by the above code is as follows,

```
Sun Nov 30 22:07:51 IST 2008
```

even though we are attempting to parse the date `2009-01-28-09:11:12`. It looks somewhat wonky. Why does it parse so?

Comment: Are you asking where Nov 30 2008 came from, or just how to fix it?

Comment: Yes It is. The following answer(s) are satisfactory but the actual question is why does it display so when I use the date format as mentioned in the question? If the date format is invalid, it shouldn't be parsed and if it's valid, it should be parse correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't your date format be something like this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss");
```

to match this format:

```
Date d = df.parse("2009-01-28-09:11:12");
```

?

As for why, per this:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

the parser actually looks at these as numbers, and the trick is that - is a part of a number, representing negative numbers. So if you do:

```
df.parse("2009-01-02-00:00:00")
```

it gives:

```
Mon Dec 01 00:02:00 EST 2008
```

That parses 2009 as yyyy, then -0 as MM (which is previous month as months start from 1), then 1 as dd, etc.

As per parse in DateFormat:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)

> By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the format by calling setLenient(false).

I guess, if you have an option, it would be better to use slashes instead of dashes, if you like formats like 2009/01/02 12:34:56. This:

```
df.parse("2009/01/02-00:00:00")
```

will throw an exception:

```
ERROR java.text.ParseException:
Unparseable date: "2009/01/02-00:00:00"
```

I can only conclude it's a very good thing that `/` is not considered a number division by DateFormat...

Comment: I can now imagine that the year is easy, just 2009. In our interpretation of month, there is no such month as 0. January would be 1. So it would be one month before January, in other words `December 2008`. The day is the 1st. Next comes the hour, which I would have imagined should have been set to 28, but was read as -2. Perhaps due to the confusing `yyyyMMdd` start, the time was offset by one character. Since hour is -2, minute is set to 8 and second to -09. If we subtract 2 hours from 1st `Dec 2008`, we come to 22:00:00 on the `30th Nov 2008`.

Comment: We then add 8 minutes and subtract 9 seconds, thus having 7 minutes and 51 seconds. The end result is 30th Nov 2008 22:07:51.

Comment: How I think it gets interpreted: `year = 2009 ;
    month = -0 ;
    day = 1 ;
    hour = -2 ;
    minute = 8 ;
    second = -09`

Comment: Exactly - and I must say this is the worst default behavior I've ever seen so far. Granted, dates are hard given the variety, but still I'd have it be strict by default. Also note that parsing goes from the start, so we don't run into problem with `:` - they are just ignored as they are after the 9, which is the last part parsed. Very interesting date parsing case...

Comment: Thanks very much for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* define the format that you actually *are* parsing...

Answer (score 1):

The dates are parsed in lenient mode by default. This means that it's forgiving to errors like parsing feb 29 as mar 1 if it's not a leap year. What you are asking it to parse is the -28th day of the -1st month of 2009, and it dutifully tries to give you exactly what you ask for.

To turn off this behaviour call format.setLenient(false). Then the dateformat will throw an exception if you try to parse something that's not a real date.